# Different security information from the security tab and ACL

Tags: powershell

I use the following cmdlets to retrieve the ACL info from a folder

```
$dirObject = Get-ChildItem -Path \\cncr1ims2001\logs -directory

$acl = $dirObject.GetAccessControl().Access
```

I looped through each entry in $acl and picked up the IdentityReference thinking they should match what's display in the Security tab when you launch the Property window via the File Explorer.

But they don't match.

From the Property window, I can see 3 entries: 1 individual user, 1 local administrator group and 1 local user group.

GetAccessControl gave me the individual user, but it doesn't show the admin group and the user group.

Any idea what I am missing?  Thanks!

Comment: You may want to use `Get-Item` instead of `Get-ChildItem` if you want the ACL from the folder only. This works for me: `$acl = (Get-Item "\\cncr1ims2001\logs").GetAccessControl().Access`

Comment: sorry, I got the same result from get-item as well